# IPC using priority queue in Unix?

Tags: c, unix

Is there a way to achieve IPC in C using Priority Queues?
I need to send a structure from one process to another, but I'd like to assign a priority for each structure, so that the other process receives higher priority structures first.
Something like FIFO's but with priority.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [POSIX Message Queues](http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/mq_overview.html) and SysV message queues can handle priorities.  A POSIX queue will always return the oldest message of the highest priority on a read.  SysV queues return a message of any (specified) priority given with the read.

Comment: But as I understood, POSIX Message Queues can only send strings. Is there a way to send a structure?

Comment: They aren't limited to strings, in fact strings can sometimes be problematic because the size needs to be limited to queue size and so forth.  Essentially they will pass whatever bytes they are given including structures of binary data.

Comment: Use posix if you can, the priority mechanism is built-in.  With sysv you have to mess with message types.